# Understanding higher order differentials and their properties

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

In our course in calculus/real analysis we defined $n$-th differential of multivariable function $f:\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}$ as:
$$d^{n}f(\vec{x},\vec{h})=\frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}f(\vec{x}+t\vec{h})\biggr\rvert_{t=0}   \text{    } (*)$$

There is an explicit formula for this differential in terms of partial derivatives which is quite similar to the multinomial theorem.

Now we used this formula to find higher order partial derivatives all at once by finding higher order differentials. In order to find them we used the following properties:
$$d(f+g)=df+dg$$
$$d(f\cdot g)=g\cdot df+f\cdot dg \text{ where $f$ and $g$ are differential expressions*}$$
$$d(dx)=0 \text{ where $x$ is an independent variable}$$

We used these properties to find higher-order differentials in the following way:

Suppose we have $f(x,y)=xy$. Then $df=y\cdot dx+x\cdot dy$. Then we would find second-order differential:
$$d^{2}f=d(df)=d(y\cdot dx+x\cdot dy)=d(y\cdot dx)+d(x\cdot dy)=dydx+yd(dx)+dxdy+xd(dy)=dxdy+y\cdot 0 + dxdy+ x\cdot0=2dxdy$$
We usually used this method to find all higher order partial derivatives at once by finding the differential of the same order. In the example above we can deduce that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=0$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=2/2=1$

While these properties were quite useful for finding higher-order differentials, we haven't proved them(moreover it was said that there is no textbook which covers such proof). And actually I can't imagine how is it possible to approach at proving this, because we haven't defined "differential of a differential expression". But after reading about [higher order Frechet derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Higher_derivatives) I realized that these differentials are just derivatives(which are multilinear functions) evaluated at the diagonal(i.e. $d^{n}f(\vec{x},\vec{h})=D^nf(\vec{x})(\vec{h},\vec{h},\dots,\vec{h})$). Is this the right way of viewing "higher order differentials" ? Is it possible to prove the properties mentinoned earlier using this definition ? What is the rigorous way of viewing this "differential operator" $d$ ? Is there some textbook which covers this topic in rigorous way ?

*It was asked in the comments what "differential expression" actually means. We were not given a rigorous definition, but it seemed clear at the time that it meant something like "sum of products of functions and $dx_i$ where $x_i$ is a variable".

Comment: what do you mean by a "differential expression"?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Expression which involves differentials of independent variables. I think I should probably give an example of what I mean in the post.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathscr{L}}\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$To skip to the end:

> differentials are just derivatives (which are multilinear functions) evaluated at the diagonal

To be pedantic, Frechet derivatives are not usually linear or multilinear. For a map $f:U\to Y$ where $U\subseteq X$ is an open subset and $X,Y$ are normed linear spaces, the Frechet derivative (if it exists) $\d_f$ is a function $U\to\L(X;Y)$. This function doesn't need to be linear; if it *is* linear then in fact $\d^2_f$ is constant and $\d^n_f$ is zero for $n\ge3$. However, $\d_f(x)$ (which is a function $X\to Y$) does need to be linear (and continuous) for any $x\in U$, and under the isomorphisms $\L(X;\L(X;Y))\cong\L^2(X;Y)$ $\d^2_f(x)$ should be bilinear for any $x$, $\d^3_f(x)$ should always be trilinear, et cetera.

Your $\d^n_f(x,h)$ looks more like a [Gateaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative). Gateaux differentiability is strictly weaker than Frechet differentiability. If $f$ is twice Frechet differentiable, it's twice Gateaux differentiable with $\d_f(x,h)=\d_f(x)(h)$ and $\d^2_f(x,h)=\frac{\d}{\d t}\Big |_{t=0}\d_f(x+th)(h)$; let's carefully use the chain rule to evaluate this.

The right hand side is (for some sufficiently small neighbourhood $V$ of zero): $$V\overset{t\mapsto x+th}{\longrightarrow}U\overset{\d_f}{\longrightarrow}\L(X;Y)\overset{e_h}{\longrightarrow}Y$$Where $e_h$ is evaluation at $h$. The composite $V\to\L(X;Y)$ has derivative $\d^2_f(x)\circ(t\mapsto ht)=t\mapsto t\cdot\d^2_f(x)(h)\in\L(X;Y)$ at zero by the chain rule. Noticing that $e_h$ is linear, its derivative is constantly equal to itself, so we should have the derivative of the overall map $V\to Y$ at zero is $(\Delta e_h)(\d_f(x))\circ(t\mapsto t\cdot\d^2_f(x)(h))=e_h(t\mapsto t\cdot\d^2_f(x)(h))=t\mapsto t\cdot\d^2_f(x)(h)(h)$ so it follows $\d^2_f(x,h)=\d^2_f(x)(h)(h)$ as expected. Under the identification $\L(X;\L(X;Y))\cong\L^2(X;Y)$ we do have $\d^2_f(x,h)=\d^2_f(x)(h,h)$. And so on; you're right that *Gateaux* differentiation *at a point* becomes evaluation of the *Frechet* derivative *at that point* at the diagonal.

As for how to prove the claims you make, these aren't really claims at all for "differential expressions". It seems your calculus class just wanted some system of formal manipulations but it's very easy to lose track of the meaning.

For example, if $f:(x,y)\mapsto xy$ from $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, what do you *really* mean when you say $\d_f=y\cdot\d x+x\cdot\d y$?? Before we answer that we should state "$\d(fg)=g\cdot\d f+f\cdot\d g$" more carefully.

> If $f,g:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R$ are differentiable then $fg$ is differentiable with Gateaux derivative: $$\d_{fg}(x,h)=g(x)\cdot\d_f(x,h)+f(x)\cdot\d_g(x,h)$$

"$y$" and "$x$" there refer to the projections $\pi_2,\pi_1:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$. $\d x,\d y$ should refer to the Gateaux derivatives of these projections. What's that? For $a\in\Bbb R^2$, $\pi_1(a+th)=\pi_1(a)+t\cdot\pi_1(h)$ and it follows that the Gateaux derivative is $\d_{\pi_1}(a,h)=\pi_1(h)$. So, "$\d x$" needs to be the map $(x,h)\mapsto\pi_1(h)$, i.e. the map to the "$x$-coordinate" of $h$. Similarly for $g$.

Overall we find: $$\d_f((x,y),h)=\pi_2(x,y)\cdot\d_{\pi_1}((x,y),h)+\pi_1(x,y)\cdot\d_{\pi_2}((x,y),h)=y\cdot h_x+x\cdot h_y$$Which is correct, and a lot less sloppy in my view than "$\d(xy)=y\cdot\d x+x\cdot\d y$".

How do we prove this rule? Well you can use the ordinary product rule for functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$: $$\frac{\d}{\d t}(fg)(x+th)\Big |_{t=0}=\left[g(x+th)\cdot\frac{\d}{\d t}f(x+th)+f(x+th)\cdot\frac{\d}{\d t}g(x+th)\right]\Big|_{t=0}\\=g(x)\cdot\d_f(x,h)+f(x)\cdot\d_g(x+th)$$

The rule $\d(f+g)=\d f+\d g$ is an easy exercise and follows from the equalities: $$\frac{\d}{\d t}(f+g)(x+th)=\frac{\d}{\d t}f(x+th)+\frac{\d}{\d t}g(x+th)$$

The rule "$\d(\d x)=0$ when $x$ is an independent variable" deeply [offends me](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4722891). "Variable", it seems to me, is very rarely a useful word to pin our statements on. Rather:

> If $f$ is a constant function, then $\d_f(x,h)\equiv0$.

This is easy to prove, since $\frac{\d}{\d t}[\text{constant}]=0$. It applies to "$\d(\d x)$" (ugh) because recall "$x$", or rather the projection $\pi_1$, has $\frac{\d}{\d t}\pi_1(x+th)\equiv\pi_1(h)$ (for all $t$...) which is therefore a *constant* function ("of" $t$) so its second Gateaux derivative has to be zero.

Comment: How can we prove these properties for "higher order cases", e.g. when we find $d^2f$ by "applying" $d$ to $df$ ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Really, if you use $d$ as you do in your post - to mean the *Gateaux* derivative - it does not make sense to apply $d$ to $d f$ to get $d^2 f$. If you use Frechet differentiation then this is all well-defined. All rules hold; a constant function has zero Frechet derivative (regardless of whether or not this function is itself a derivative of some other function); the Frechet derivative of a sum of functions is the sum of derivatives; there is also a product rule though to formulate this properly is a little more subtle

Comment: $\newcommand{\L}{\mathscr{L}}\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$If $U\subseteq X$ is an open subset of a normed linear spaces and $A,B,C$ are normed linear spaces and $f:U\to\L(A;B)$ and $g:U\to\L(B;C)$ are Frechet differentiable then the map: $$U\overset{\langle g,f\rangle}{\longrightarrow}\L(B;C)\oplus\L(A;B)\overset{\circ}{\longrightarrow}\L(A;C)$$Has Frechet derivative $\d_{fg}:U\to\L(X;\L(A;C))$ given by $\d_{fg}(u)(x)=g(x)\circ\d_f(u)(x)+\d_g(u)(x)\circ f(x)$. This can be proven with the chain rule and an explicit computation of the derivative of $\circ$.

Comment: All rules for $\mathrm{d}^2$ etc. follow form formal repeated application of the derivative operator, which *is* well-defined when the functions at hand are differentiable

Comment: To recover the usual product rules from what I just wrote, note that under $\Bbb R\cong\mathscr{L}(\Bbb R;\Bbb R)$ composition corresponds to multiplication