# How does this proof of $\ln(xy)= \ln(x)+ \ln(y) $ correctly apply the integral definition of $\ln(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

I am quite confused about how the integral definition is used to prove $\ln(xy)= \ln(x)+ \ln(y) $ below,  especially in how it does not treat the integrand as a strict reciprocal function; and even if it did I am not seeing how the bounds apply. Here is the proof I am reading:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\ln x y & = \int_1^{x y} d t / t \\
& =\int_1^x d t / t+\int_x^{x y} d t / t
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, let $u= \frac {t}{x}$, so, $t=u x$ and $d t=x \cdot d u$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{t} d t=\frac{1}{u x} \cdot x d u=\frac{1}{u} d u$, so the above integral is
$$
\int_1^x \frac {d t}  t+\int_1^y \frac{du} u=\ln x+\ln y
$$
I have three questions here:

1. When we conclude that $\int_1^y \frac{du} u=\ln y$ using the definition $\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac {dt}t$, I thought that $t$ must be a single variable, not any function, such that the integrand is exactly the reciprocal function. However, here we have a function $u$ which is not defined as just a single variable. How is claiming this integral is the $\ln$ definition justified?
2. If we are going to make the argument that $\frac {du} u$ represents the reciprocal function $\frac {dt}t$, and on that account apply the definition, are we not unjustified in using the bounds of integration for $u$ when we interpret the integral as being with respect to $t$? If we say the integral definition of $\ln(x)$ applies here due to the integrand really being $\frac {dt}t$, which is strictly the reciprocal function, it seems we can only make this argument when the bounds of integration are the original $x$ and $xy$, and the definition of $\ln(y)$ would still not apply as we cannot use the bounds  $1$ and $y$, which are the bounds for $u$ not $t$.
3. When we have used properties of integrals to break up $\int_1^{x y} \frac {d t}  t$ into 2 integrals, how does this work when $x$ and $y$ are variables? Do we treat them as constants here? I am not sure whether we can use this property of integrals for variables.

Comment: Consider the integration range of a box with the four corner points being $\{ (1, 1), \, (x, 1), \, (1, y), \, (x,y) \, \}$. In this range consider integration along the paths or over the region. For example $\int_{1}^{x} + \int_{1}^{y}$ is the addition of outside of either the lower triangle or upper triangle.

Comment: 1. $u$ is not a function but a new integration variable. 2. By this change of variable, the integral for $t$ from $x$ to $xy$ becomes the integral for $u$ from $1$ to $y, $ and $(dt)/t$ becomes $(xdu)/(xu).$ 3. $x,y$ are *arbitrary* constants here.

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks; does this mean if we were to graph $\frac {1} {u}$ according to the manner in which we interpret it, it would be the same exact graph as the reciprocal function $\frac {1} {x}$ in this question, even if we had let $u$ be some complex expression earlier, and expressing $u$ in terms of $x$ gives some quadratic function?

Comment: Once the change of *variable* is done, you can forget the "complex expression". And the letter used to denote an integration variable is completely arbitrary. $$\int_1^y(du)/u=\int_1^y(ds)/s=\int_1^y(dt)/t.$$ You do not "express $u$ in terms of $x$" here. Again: $x$ is a constant.

Comment: @AnneBauval does this mean the integrals $\int_1^y \frac{du} u$ and $\int_x^{x y} d t / t$ are mathematically equivalent objects here? if the variable is arbitrary, I am currently seeing that these should be distinct mathematical objects (as they are integrals with the same integrand but different bounds) but within the bounds of this question they seem identical.

Comment: They are equal. You must review your lecture about the change of variable.$\int_x^{x y} f(t)d t =\int_1^yf(xu)x d u .$

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry but what is the reason why $x$ and $y$ are constants here when they are parameters to the log function; is $x$ not a variable in $\ln    (x)$?

Comment: They are *arbitrary* constants during the proof. After proving the equation for every positive value of these constants, they can be considered as variables whenever necessary.

Comment: I think you're making this really complicated. According to the Wiki, the words "variable" and "constant" seem to have multiple meanings. I don't see any point in wondering about which is a variable and which is a constant when it comes to the proof in question. The main idea behind the proof is that you split up the integral and do a substitution on one of the integrals. I'm not saying your questions are dumb (they aren't IMO), but I doubt the proof was intended for people to ponder things like constants, variables, single variables, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$In formal logic, I am *under the impression* (I know nothing of the subject) that there are some precise definitions of constants and logical variables.

Outside of that context, it is my opinion that discussion of constant/variable is only useful for the intuition, and that these words are convenient **fictions** to help us understand a situation. These words have clearly confused you greatly and I've seen them confuse my friends, very often, but there is little to no meaningful difference between them.

If you make things more precise with elements and functions, then you will not get confused (given a certain 'mathematical maturity'). "$u$" on its own is a meaningless symbol. $u=t/x$ is implicitly defining a function $u:[1,x]\to\Bbb R$ that maps $t\mapsto t/x$. In the same way, "$t$" on its own has no meaning, unless you tell me - hey, here is some $t\in [1,x]$. Then I know $t$ *denotes* some element of the interval $[1,x]$. I still do not care in the slightest about "$t$"'s status as a constant or a variable; I perceive that to be a meaningless question.

> 1. When we conclude that $\int_1^y \frac{du} u=\ln y$ using the definition $\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac {dt}t$, I thought that $t$ must be a single variable, not any function, such that the integrand is exactly the reciprocal function. However, here we have a function $u$ which is not defined as just a single variable. How is claiming this integral is the $\ln$ definition justified?

The definition: $$\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\d t$$Is more precisely saying: $\ln:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ is the function which takes an positive real $x$ to the real number $\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\d t$. Think about how that integral is actually defined: nowhere does the definition say, "hey! Give me '$t$' as an input, or else!" We may as well integrate $\frac{1}{\text{cucumber}}\d\,\text{cucumber}$. I might want to define $g:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ by $a\mapsto1/a$ and then say, $\ln(x):=\int_1^x g$. This expression is well-defined, and suppresses any notation of the "variable" $t$.
$\int_1^y\frac{1}{u}\d u$ means *exactly the same thing* as $\int_1^yg$. Earlier, we had defined the function $u:t\mapsto t/x$, but the notation $\int\frac{1}{u}\d u$ does not care about that function $u$; I suppose this is an abuse of notation, since the symbol $u$ is being overloaded. Maybe this 'abuse' is the main source of your confusion: when handling the "change-of-variable", you must *forget* the previous definition.

We can state the "change-of-variable" formula without mentioning "other variables":

> Under suitable conditions with suitable functions $F,G$ we have: $$\int_{A}F=\int_{G^{-1}(A)}(F\circ G)G'$$

We can also state it using just one symbol to denote our "variable":

> Under suitable conditions with suitable functions $F,G$ we have; $$\int_AF(t)\d t=\int_{G^{-1}(A)}F(G(t))\cdot G'(t)\d t$$I do **not** need to start by saying something like, "let $t=G(u)$..." nor do I need to stick with the letters $u$ or $t$. They are symbols, placeholders, used to get a convenient notation for the integral. Some people might write, "let $t\mapsto G(t)$", and this is also fine; it is all just human-friendly fluff to suggest why the left hand side equals the right hand side.

It may be helpful for you to internalise this formula. I deliberately avoided attaching any specific notation to the inputs of the functions $F$ and $(F\circ G)G'$, to emphasise that such notation is *placeholder* notation.

Whether or not $u$ is a "single variable" is irrelevant. In isolation, what does that even mean? This is not physics, where we are modelling a moving object '$u$' whose value really does vary because, as we speak, it is rolling down a hill. No. In $\int\frac{1}{u}\d u$, $u$ is a placeholder for a real number. It is no more or less variable than the symbol $1$. The notation just indicates a little something about how the (Riemann) integral is defined: you take some interval $(u,u+h)$ and add $h\cdot 1/u$ to the Riemann sum... where $u$ may be any real number at all, in the interval $[1,x]$.

> 2. If we are going to make the argument that $\frac {du} u$ represents the reciprocal function $\frac {dt}t$, and on that account apply the definition, are we not unjustified in using the bounds of integration for $u$ when we interpret the integral as being with respect to $t$? If we say the integral definition of $\ln(x)$ applies here due to the integrand really being $\frac {dt}t$, which is strictly the reciprocal function, it seems we can only make this argument when the bounds of integration are the original $x$ and $xy$, and the definition of $\ln(y)$ would still not apply as we cannot use the bounds  $1$ and $y$, which are the bounds for $u$ not $t$.

We don't need to make any argument at all. $\frac{1}{u}\d u$ and $\frac{1}{t}\d t$ are themselves both meaningless (caveat: I ignore the $\d$ notations that do have meaning in other areas of maths) outside of the integral sign $\int$ and, strictly speaking, $\frac{1}{u}$ does not represent a function any more than $\frac{1}{t}$ does. These are placeholder symbols for the function $a\mapsto1/a$, or for $t\mapsto1/t$, or for $\text{eggs}\mapsto1/\text{eggs}$... the symbol used is irrelevant. Remember, in the change-of-variables formula, when we 'switch' to $1/u\d u$ we **forget** the previous definition of the symbol $u$ as a function ($t\mapsto t/x$).

"Bounds for $u$ not $t$" doesn't make sense. $1,y,x,xy$ are all real numbers. The integral is well-defined irrelevant of which numbers you use as in the limit. The integral definition of $\ln$ does *not* apply to the integrand "really being $1/t \d t$". The integral definition of $\ln$, strictly speaking, applies to the integrand $g$. $1/t \d t$ is merely a convenient way to denote the integral, but you mustn't cling to this notation - it is, again, *placeholder* notation. The integral does not "care" what the letters are inside of it, nor does it care what its bounds are. $\int_1^y g$ makes equal sense to $\int_x^{xy} g$. The definitions apply, equally, and these equal $\ln(y)-\ln(1)$ and $\ln(xy)-\ln(x)$ respectively (these are in fact the same value).

> 3. When we have used properties of integrals to break up $\int_1^{x y} \frac {d t}  t$ into 2 integrals, how does this work when $x$ and $y$ are variables? Do we treat them as constants here? I am not sure whether we can use this property of integrals for variables.

$x$ and $y$ are not really "variables" because "variables" doesn't really mean anything here. In $\ln xy=\cdots$, $x$ and $y$ are implicitly assumed to denote *some* positive real numbers. The only purpose of giving them a "generic" symbol like "$x$" is to suggest that, when we eventually show $\ln xy=\ln x+\ln y$, that this equation will be true for *all* possible $x,y$. But $x$ may as well be $\pi$, or $e$, or $1$, or $2$. $\int_a^b h$ makes sense where $h$ is a function, and $a,b$ are real numbers. The 'variability' of $a,b,h$ is not meaningful and is certainly irrelevant.

You can use this property of integrals because examining any proof of this property together with any definition of integral reveals, again, that the integral "does not care" about such concerns of "variable, constant" etc.