# What is going on when we change variables in pdes/odes?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, trigonometry

Lets consider a simple example
\begin{align*}
y'(x) = g(x)
\end{align*}
One can solve this by direct integration assuming.

I want to use this to study what change of variables really is. Say that we wanted to change variables to say $z=-x$. Then by the chain rule
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dz} = -\frac{dy}{dx}.
\end{align*}
And so
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dz} (z) = -g(-z).
\end{align*}
Now lets write the two formally
\begin{align*}
Dy (x) = g(x) \quad \text{and} \quad Dy(-z) = -g(-z).
\end{align*}
This can not be right I think. This is because if this is true then simply relabeling, as this is allowed in the definition of $Df$, we have that the second is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
Dy (x) = - g(x).
\end{align*}
This would imply that
\begin{align*}
g(x) = -g(x) \implies g(x) = 0
\end{align*}
which need not be true.

I assume that what is going on is that I don't really understand, formally, either of the notations
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} \quad \text{or} \quad  y' (x).
\end{align*}

Could someone formally define what these are in terms of the derivative function $Dy$ and explain what is going on here?

Comment: The operations "relabelling $x$ by $-x$" and "differentiating" do not commute: your statement $Dy(-z) = -g(-z)$ is false. Try using accurate notations, by defining $\tilde{y}(x) = y(-x)$ for instance, and keep track where you are considering $\tilde{y}$ and $y$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812800/8157).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given functions $y,g$ on suitable domains. Define a new function $z$. Now, there are two cases: either there is an obvious choice of function $y_1$ such that $y=y_1\circ z$ but if not you have to assume $z$ is (*locally*) invertible (with sufficiently well-differentiable and continuous inverse) and define $y_1:=y\circ z^{-1}$ such that this holds. Same story for $g$... get a $g_1$, somehow, that $g=g_1\circ z$.

Now we know $y'=(y_1z)'=(y_1'\circ z)\cdot z'$, so $z'\cdot(y'_1\circ z)=g_1\circ z$ would be your new differential equation. If $z'$ itself is expressible as some composition $z_1\circ z$ then that's even better, and you obtain $z_1\cdot y'_1=g_1$ identically on the image of $z$.

[I don't really like "variables"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4722891) but it is an undeniably useful concept to have in mind when handling differential equations; yet clearly it is important that we are taught a way to actually capture what is going on, to know what's right. Conversations along the lines of "oh but *this* depends on *that* and when you partially differentiate *this* variable those ones are constant even though they depend on the same thing and and and .. . " can so very easily go wrong.

In the case of $z:x\mapsto-x$, $z'\equiv-1$ and we may take $z_1$ to be the constant function at $-1$. Of course, $y_1$ would be $t\mapsto y(-t)$ and $g_1$ would be $t\mapsto g(-t)$, as $z$ is self inverse.

Then we find $z_1\cdot y'_1=g_1$, or $-y'(z)=g(z)$ in loose notation, where one thinks of $z$ as a "new variable" replacing "$x$". **Important**: if you use the notational abuse where you keep referring to the same function $y$, it is actually more useful to fully embrace Leibniz's notation where variable dependence is clear. I wrote $y'$, you wrote $Dy$, and in both cases - if we are to abuse the letter $y$ - we can run afoul of our abuses... Leibniz notation is built to (*partially*, it introduces new problems) fix this, so in the spirit of the thing I should write $-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z}=g(z)$. *Even though $g$ is not the same $g$*. For instance if $g:x\mapsto x^3+x$, then "$g(z)$" is not $z^3+z$ but rather $-z^3-z$, since $x=-z$ right? Really, it is the *new function* $g_1$ which has $g_1:t\mapsto -t^3-t$.